# execve() - Error:: No such file or directory in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, execve

I am having an issue with the execve(). I am trying to write a simple shell program that will read input from the user using the getline() and then execute it using execve().
When i enter a command(input), i get this error message:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-focal:~/shell_exercises$ ./shell
#cisfun$ /bin/ls
line: /bin/ls
argv[0]: /bin/ls
Error:: No such file or directory
#cisfun$
```

i have tried to running the program with the path=/bin/ls, but it's not working. What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance. here is the code:

```
int main(void)
{
  char *line, *argv[] = { NULL, NULL }, *env[] = {NULL};
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t nread;

  do {
    printf("#cisfun$ ");
    nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin);
    if (nread == -1)
    {
      perror("can't read command\n");
      exit(95);
    }
    printf("line: %s", line);

    if (line == NULL)
    {
      printf("hello dawg");
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      argv[0] = line;
      printf("argv[0]: %s", argv[0]);
      if (execve(line, argv, env) == -1)
      {
        perror("Error:");
      }
    }
  } while (1);

  free(line);
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Improve your code with `char *line=NULL;` then compile it with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Read documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and man page of [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Read documentation of [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) then use it. If allowed, use also [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and read about [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). Learn to use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Of the excellent advice above -- in particular, `strace -f -s 2048 -o myshell.trace ./shell` is the most direct way to answer your question about why the `execve()` is failing for yourself.

Comment: The `getline()` function includes the newline in the string.  You need to remove it before using it with `execve()`.

Answer (score 1):

here is the code:

```
int main(void)
{
```

Read [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [getline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

### Some headers are missing.

At least `#include <stdio.h>` (mentioned in [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)) and `#include <unistd.h>` (mentioned in [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html); you may want to read also [exec(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) and [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)..)

Then compile your `bayer.c` source code with all warnings and debug info:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g bayer.c -o bayershell
```

improve the C code to get *no warnings*

Then read the documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) (the debugger) then try `gdb --help` then

```
 gdb bayershell
```

Be aware of [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and that **every shell should use [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)** (gurus could try [clone(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)...) since it needs to start processes (and later [waitpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for them)

You probably need to read [stdio(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) then [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) and tutorial slides about Linux (in French I wrote [these](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/intro-programmation-sous-Linux.pdf)).

In English read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) or a better book.

### Study the source code of existing open source shells

Like [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

You probably would want to **use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) to compile your shell project**. You need to read its documentation.

You may want to use [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) on your source code. I recommend using a **version control system** like [git](https://git-scm.com/) (perhaps on [github](https://github.com/)). It is helpful against mistakes (like removing a source code file), if used correctly.

What would happen if `nread` is less than `len` ?

Consider also learning and using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).

Notice that [getline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) is reading the end-of-line character. On most Linux systems, there is no file named `"/bin/ls\n"` (whose name ends with the newline). You could need [strchr(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) to remove the ending newline character `\n`. You could even consider using [GNU readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (it may reuse a previous buffer), and considering latter some autocompletion...

Today, computers use UTF8. Read about [UTF8 everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/). My (French) keyboard has keys for § and ° and your user could copy/paste `∃` from his/her web browser.

Comment: thanks sir, it worked. i copied what was in "line" variable into a buffer by excluding the '\n', then used it in the execve()